# PJSIP TLS connect() error: End of file (PJ_EEOF) [code=70016]

Tags: ios, ssl, pjsip

I'm getting this EOF error when attempting to register my iOS project with my Asterisk server. Without TLS everything is working. So I'm now going through the process of enabling TLS. I've recompiled the PJSIP libraries and configured the Asterisk server. I believe that is all correct. I can see the traffic occurring in an encrypted form over port 5161 so that appears to be correct as well.

1) What I'm curious about is what could cause this error? Could it be the certificates that I generated? Based on the fact that I see encrypted traffic on wireshark but not in the Asterisk pjsip logger is making me thing it's the cert?

2) Second question is how do you create a certificate for a client who's hostname will be unknown (i.e. their IP will obviously change as they roam on cellular or to different WIFI networks). When I created them according to the Asterisk tutorial (https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Tutorial) it required a value for the -C parameter to specify the client hostname. Which again this would assumed to be dynamic.

Here's the log output (personal info [REDACTED])...

```
15:26:15.857 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.6 for POSIX initialized
15:26:15.858 sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
15:26:15.859          pjlib  .select() I/O Queue created (0x11e809228)
15:26:15.859 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" registered
15:26:15.859 sip_transport.  .Transport manager created.
15:26:15.859   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: NULL --> CREATED
15:26:15.859 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered
15:26:15.859 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered
15:26:15.859 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" registered
15:26:15.859 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" registered
15:26:15.859 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" registered
15:26:15.859 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" registered
15:26:15.860 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" registered
15:26:15.888 coreaudio_dev.  .. dev_id 0: iPhone IO device  (in=1, out=1) 8000Hz
15:26:15.888 coreaudio_dev.  ..core audio initialized
15:26:15.888          pjlib  ..select() I/O Queue created (0x11e16fc28)
15:26:15.888  speex_codec.c  ..Adjusting quality to 5 for uwb
15:26:15.889   conference.c  ..Creating conference bridge with 12 ports
15:26:15.889   Master/sound  ..Using delay buffer with WSOLA.
15:26:15.907 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" registered
15:26:15.907 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-presence" registered
15:26:15.907        evsub.c  .Event pkg "presence" registered by mod-presence
15:26:15.907 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-mwi" registered
15:26:15.907        evsub.c  .Event pkg "message-summary" registered by mod-mwi
15:26:15.907 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-refer" registered
15:26:15.907        evsub.c  .Event pkg "refer" registered by mod-refer
15:26:15.907 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-pres" registered
15:26:15.907 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-im" registered
15:26:15.907 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-options" registered
15:26:15.908   pjsua_core.c  .1 SIP worker threads created
15:26:15.908   pjsua_core.c  .pjsua version 2.6 for iOS-10.2.1/arm-iPad6,7/iOS-SDK initialized
15:26:15.908   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: CREATED --> INIT
15:26:15.910     tlstp:5161  SIP TLS listener is ready for incoming connections at 10.200.154.118:5161
15:26:15.910   pjsua_core.c  PJSUA state changed: INIT --> STARTING
15:26:15.910 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-unsolicited-mwi" registered
15:26:15.910   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: STARTING --> RUNNING
15:26:15.910    pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=sip:[REDACTED]@[REDACTED]
15:26:15.910    pjsua_acc.c  .Account sip:[REDACTED]@[REDACTED] added with id 0
15:26:15.910    pjsua_acc.c  .Acc 0: setting registration..
15:26:15.912 tlsc0x11e18882  ..TLS client transport created
15:26:15.912 tlsc0x11e18882  ..TLS transport 10.200.154.118:58635 is connecting to [REDACTED]:5161...
15:26:15.912    pjsua_acc.c  ..Contact for acc 0 updated: <sip:[REDACTED]@10.200.154.118:58635;transport=TLS;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-00009c3fe9b2>"
15:26:15.912       endpoint  ..Request msg REGISTER/cseq=10712 (tdta0x11e950400) created.
15:26:15.913 tsx0x11e9524a8  ...Transaction created for Request msg REGISTER/cseq=10713 (tdta0x11e950400)
15:26:15.913 tsx0x11e9524a8  ..Sending Request msg REGISTER/cseq=10713 (tdta0x11e950400) in state Null
15:26:15.913  sip_resolve.c  ...Target '[REDACTED]:5161' type=TLS resolved to '[REDACTED]:5161' type=TLS (TLS transport)
15:26:15.913   pjsua_core.c  ...TX 730 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=10713 (tdta0x11e950400) to TLS [REDACTED]:5161:
REGISTER sip:[REDACTED]:5161;transport=tls SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.200.154.118:58635;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjYEl90guBh1gvKz2dDJZlgxzyy7AzLMpx;alias

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:[REDACTED]@[REDACTED]>;tag=V6bPvLX5S0jBnpssQQBhG1W2xhXz01gj

To: <sip:[REDACTED]@[REDACTED]>

Call-ID: 5h.iiZFsYAX2vtMCNx.ZmH9NsicZoQEX

CSeq: 10713 REGISTER

User-Agent: [REDACTED]

Supported: outbound, path

Contact: <sip:[REDACTED]@10.200.154.118:58635;transport=TLS;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-00009c3fe9b2>"

Expires: 300

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
15:26:15.914 tsx0x11e9524a8  ...State changed from Null to Calling, event=TX_MSG
15:26:15.914    pjsua_acc.c  ..Acc 0: Registration sent
15:26:16.001 tlsc0x11e18882 !TLS connect() error: End of file (PJ_EEOF) [code=70016]
15:26:16.001 tsx0x11e9524a8  Failed to send Request msg REGISTER/cseq=10713 (tdta0x11e950400)! err=70016 (End of file (PJ_EEOF))
15:26:16.001 tsx0x11e9524a8  State changed from Calling to Terminated, event=TRANSPORT_ERROR
15:26:16.001    pjsua_acc.c  ..SIP registration failed, status=503 (End of file (PJ_EEOF))
15:26:16.001    pjsua_acc.c  ..Scheduling re-registration retry for acc 0 in 2 seconds..
15:26:16.001 PJSIPInterface  ..AccountID 0 reg_state=503
15:26:16.001 tlsc0x11e18882  TLS send() error, sent=-70016
15:26:16.001    pjsua_acc.c  Disconnected notification for transport tlsc0x11e188828
15:26:16.001 tsx0x11e9524a8  Timeout timer event
15:26:16.001 tsx0x11e9524a8  .State changed from Terminated to Destroyed, event=TIMER
15:26:16.001 tdta0x11e95040  ..Destroying txdata Request msg REGISTER/cseq=10713 (tdta0x11e950400)
15:26:16.001 tsx0x11e9524a8  Transaction destroyed!
15:26:16.001 tlsc0x11e18882  TLS transport destroyed with reason 70016: End of file (PJ_EEOF)
```

Here's my transport setup code in my iOS app...

```
        pjsua_transport_config tlsTransportConfig;
        pjsua_transport_config_default(&tlsTransportConfig);
        tlsTransportConfig.port = 5161;

        tlsTransportConfig.tls_setting.ca_list_file = pj_str((char*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ca.crt" ofType:@"pem"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        tlsTransportConfig.tls_setting.cert_file = pj_str((char*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myapp.crt" ofType:@"pem"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        tlsTransportConfig.tls_setting.privkey_file = pj_str((char*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myapp.key" ofType:@"pem"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        tlsTransportConfig.tls_setting.password = pj_str("[REDACTED]");
        tlsTransportConfig.tls_setting.verify_client = PJ_TRUE;
        tlsTransportConfig.tls_setting.verify_server = PJ_TRUE;
        tlsTransportConfig.tls_setting.method = PJSIP_SSLV2_METHOD;

        status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS, &tlsTransportConfig, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue. As per a tutorial I was following I had set the tls method to **PJSIP_SSLV2_METHOD** as you can see in my code above. However when I changed this to **PJSIP_TLSV1_METHOD** everything started working. This also requires this to be changed in the PJSIP settings for the SSL method as well.

I'm not sure why SSLV2 didn't work but tlsv1 works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this also might relate to the server side. If the server you are using is Opensips it might be that SIP message is too fragmented and OpenSIPS closes the connection to prevent packets fragmentation attacks, default value is 4.
Changing the .cfg file on the server option should fix the issue

modparam("proto_tls", "tls_max_msg_chunks", 8)